# split PDF by Pages php/js

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, imagemagick, pdftk

i am trying to achieve the following:
i have a PDF with bout 50-100 Pages.

When the file is uploaded, i want to display every page.
For this i found a solution "ImageMagick" - i create for every page a jpg and display the jpg's in a grid.

Now the user should be able to select ranges for the displayed pages.
I would love to do it like "splitpdfpages.com" - after every page (image) there are "scissors" where the ranges can be defined. Let's say i select the scissors after page1, then after page3, then after page6 and so on.
The range would be: 1, 2-3, 4-6 etc.
The problem i have, i don't know for what should i search and have no clue how to achieve this.

the final thing is, to make a file for each selected page-range - for that i have found a solution "pdftk".

i hope i could explain it well and someone could give me a hint if there is any library or even the right search for that function/behaivour.

thank you very much

Comment: In Imagemagick you can select any random set of pages image.pdf[0,3,9,15] would read or view or process the first, 4th, 10th and 16th pages

Comment: Use JS (client-side) to record the marked scissors, then submit to PHP to do the split. say if you have 10 pages and you marked 1, 3, 6 . Pass this array of numbers to the PHP and use a simple function (a loop is already enough) to calculate the result. -- the split page ranges will be (**1** to `1`) (2 to `3`) (4 to `6`) and (7 to **10**)  where 1 and 10 are the first page and last page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The [LEADTOOLS Hosted Cloud Services](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/hosted-services) offer a web API that can generate a new PDF file for each split range by using the [Convert](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/cloud-services/convert.html) request. This can be made in JavaScript or PHP. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)